# How To Limit The Number of Times A Struct is Looped Through in Go?

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, struct, for-range

I am trying to have a `Struct` only be looped through ten times before stopping. My `Struct` looks like

```
type Book struct {
    Id string
    Title string
}
```

and the code that will loop through the entire thing is

```
var books []Book;
for _, book := range books {
    fmt.Println(book.Id + " " + book.Title);
}
```

I have tried using a separate for loop that will go ten times but that has only looped through the entire `Struct` ten times or did one part of the `Struct` ten times.

Comment: the code presented will loop through all values in `books`, so if there are 10 books, it will loop 10 times. Please create a [mre] which shows exactly the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: There are currently 17 items in the struct. I cannot recreate the example without basically pasting the entire program in.

Comment: The number of fields in the struct is not relevant for looping over a series of those struct values. A "minimal reproducible example" does not mean an exact copy of your code, only the minimal portion required to explain the question.

Comment: I think the problem is with the terminology. In the example, no `struct` is iterated, but a slice of `struct`s is. I can conjure the OP wanted to limit the number of elements in a slice to be iterated; maybe limit the iteration by only considering N first elements of the slice.

Comment: If I'm correct, the simplest is to use subslicing: `for b := range books[:10] { ...`

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned by Jim in the comments sections, you are looping over all books declared on line before, which by the way is an empty slice (so you won't loop at all).

Though in a for loop over a range, the first argument is the index of the current element. With, that you can fix a condition in your loop to exit it if you overflow your arbitrary limit

```
// books is a slice of Book -> []Book
for i, book := range books {
    // If you are on the eleventh element of your slice
    if i == 10 {
        // leave the loop
        break
    }
// Do whatever you want with book
}
```